# The range of $f(x) = \sqrt{x-x^2}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

How do we find the range of $f(x) = \sqrt{x-x^2}$? I found the domain to be $0 \leq x \leq 1$. I know $f^{-1}(y)$ isn't a function, and that $y^2 + x^2 = x$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$x-x^2=\dfrac{1-(2x-1)^2}4\le\dfrac14$$

Alternatively for $0\le x \le1,$ using AM-GM inequality, $$\dfrac{x+1-x}2\ge\sqrt{x(1-x)}$$

Comment: ok understood the AM-GM proof, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, hence the range $f([0,1])$ is a compact interval $[a,b].$ Since $f \ge 0$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$, we get $a=0.$ Furthermore there is $x_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $b=f(x_0)$. Then $f'(x_0)=0.$ this gives $x_0=1/2$, therefore $b=1/2.$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that  $\;x-x^2=x(1-x)\implies\;$ this is a downwards parabola with roots at $\;x=0,\,1\;$,. and thus the graph of  $\;\sqrt{x-x^2}\;$, whenever

$$\;x(1-x)\ge 0\iff x(x-1)\le 0\iff 0\le x\le 1$$

is like the parabola's graph there but a little "flattened" . Of course, it is not the graph of a parabola but a rather similar-deformed one. From this you can deduce the image...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a geometric way

$$\sqrt{x-x^2} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}$$

in other words the graph is the upper half of a circle of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ centered at $\frac{1}{2}$. The domain and range can be deduced from this.